# Dompdf: how to get background image to show on first page only

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate letters which I want to brand with various different companies branded paper. To do this I'm getting a background image via css. See example image at bottom. I then set appropriate margins to fit the content I want to write out into the white space. However I just want this letterhead to display on the first page only. At present it is repeating onto each page. My css looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{$pdf.title}</title>
<style type="text/css">
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    padding: {$branding.page_margin_top}cm {$branding.page_margin_right}cm {$branding.page_margin_bottom}cm {$branding.page_margin_left}cm;
    font-size: 7pt;
    font-family: helvetica !important;
    background-image: url('{$base_url}pd-direct.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  #postal-address {
      margin: 0cm;
      margin-left: {$branding.address_offset_left}cm;
      margin-top: {$branding.address_offset_top}cm;
      margin-bottom: {$branding.address_offset_bottom}cm;
      font-size: 10pt;
  }
  #date {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="page-body">

      <div id="content">

        {if $pdf.postal_address}
        <div id="postal-address">
          {$pdf.postal_address|nl2br}
        </div>
        {/if}

        {$pdf.main_body}

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I change this so the background image is only displayed on the first page output by dompdf?

See current html being rendered at: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=ccfb2785f8a8ba3e1e459cbd283ad015

Comment: Have you tried `@page :first`? As far as I can remember it works with wkhtmltopdf - I'm unsure if it works with dompdf.

Comment: background-image doesn't appear to work on @page using dompdf.

Comment: Did not see these comments before posting my answer suggesting `@page :first`! Can you provide some PHP code so people can have an easier time with cut/paste testing?

Comment: @miken32 What do you mean by "Did not see these comments before posting my answer suggesting "@page" :first"? I said that background-image doesn't work with "@page" on dompdf. Posting PHP code isn't going to help as it's the HTML CSS that's the issue here not PHP. I posted a link to the current HTML being rendered using a dompdf debug tool:

http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=ccfb2785f8a8ba3e1e459cbd283ad015

Comment: I meant I posted an answer suggesting `@page :first` and then deleted it.

Comment: Ah. Follow you now. Hadn't realised there was a deleted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to get a background image showing up at all. Looks fine as HTML downloaded from your site, but then I take it and put it in a PDF and it's gone.

Comment: create a div to which you will apply the background :background-image: url('{$base_url}pd-direct.png'); and put the first page inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the letterhead as the background image in an div that overlaps the main content div and use `z-index` to organise the stacking order of the divs, so that background image will appears at the back.
This way, the background image will only show on the first page when you convert it to PDF using DOMPDF.
The CSS below works for A4@150dpi.

**CSS**

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin-top:0.5cm;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    font-family: helvetica !important;
    font-size: 10pt;
    position: relative;
  }
  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.showhousesoftware.com/pd-direct.png');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}
  #content{
    padding: 3.5cm 0.50cm 5.00cm 0.50cm;
  }
  #postal-address {
      margin: 0cm;
      margin-left: 1.50cm;
      margin-top: 0.00cm;
      margin-bottom: 1.00cm;
      font-size: 10pt;
  }
  #date {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="page-body">
<div id="overlay">
</div>
<div id="content">
......

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd take off the `size: A4;` and the `margin-top:0.5cm;` that way the background will be full...